# Inject dependencies in Mediatr command handler

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

I am using Autofac and mediatr. The flow is a message coming from `EventHub` and I process it and send it to respective command handlers. I can inject few things from the `api` projects perspective, using the `builder`.

```
builder.Register(ctx => {
   var userInfo = ctx.Resolve<UserContextProvider>().GetUserInformation();
   var connectionString = ResolveConnectionString(userInfo);
   return new Repository(connectionString);
}).As<IRepository>();
```

As the messages are comming from event hub, I need to resolve those parameters dynamically. I have injected the `IComponentContext` into my message processor class and am trying to resolve the parameters.

```
_componentContext.Resolve<ActivityCommandHandler>(new NamedParameter("conStr", ConnectionString));
```

When I put breakpoint on the handler constructor I can see the `conStr` when the above line is executed.

Is this the correct way of doing it ?

When I send the command using `_mediatr.send(mycommand)` I am getting the below exception.

> None of the constructors found with `Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder` on type `CommandHandlers.ActivityCommandHandler` can be invoked with the available services and parameters: 
>   Cannot resolve parameter `System.String conStr` of constructor `Void .ctor(AutoMapper.IMapper, MediatR.IMediator, System.String)`

Comment: It's quite unclear to me. How do you register `ActivityCommandHandler` ? how the `conStr`. Do you want to propagate the `conStr` parameter to the whole dependency graph ?

Comment: Hi @CyrilDurand thanks for the reply. I have already registered all the `IrequestHander<,>` types

Comment: OK but how did you register them ? How *Autofac* will know how to provide the `conStr` parameter ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand i did register them based on wiki from https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki

Comment: How Autofac will know how to provide the `conStr` parameter when building the `ActivityCommandHandler` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand sorry thats what im resolving using the `_componentContext` i mistyped in the question before

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use named-parameters.

Wrap information in an object and register the object itself.

Possible object structure:

```cs
public class ConnectionConfiguration 
{
   public string ConnectionString { get; }

   public ConnectionConfiguration(string connectionString) => ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

```
builder.Register(_ => new ConnectionConfiguration(ConnectionString));
```

Now inject that in your handler. No extra registration required which also doesn't work because the handlers are already registered to be resolved as open-generics as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Autofac/Program.cs#L27). The `ServiceFactory` registration takes care of creating those handlers.

FYI: I created a nuget-package for registering `MediatR` with `Autofac` that even can be used together with [default-service-provider](https://github.com/cleancodelabs/MediatR.Extensions.Autofac.DependencyInjection/blob/d92b677e655140ef02edaf5977be5fcad1a268e9/samples/MediatR.Extensions.Autofac.DepdencyInjection.Samples.WebApi/Startup.cs#L43).